# How to find a sub-string with patterns?

Tags: linux, string, find

I have a problem to extract sub-string in a long string of path. For example, I have

```
/home/usr/VIP_00011_selected/Mark/Test
/home/usr/VIP_00021_selected/Mark/Test
/home/usr/VIP_02015_selected/Mark/Test
...
```

stored as string. I would like to use find command to extract

```
'VIP_00011_selected'
```

between two / and just return

```
'VIP_00011'
```

I just asked a similar question before, but I found that directly working on path will not working as I am writing a for loop to do some operation. For example,

```
find . -type d -iname "VIP*" | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d'_' -f1,2
```

will return all the VIP* under the base folder. I would like to extract one by one for my 'for loop'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract 'VIP_00011' you can change "VIP*" -> `"VIP_[0-9]+"` or `"VIP_\d+"`

If you want to extract 'VIP_00011_selected' you can change "VIP*" -> `"VIP_[0-9]+_[a-z]+"` or `"VIP_\d+_\w+"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep` on each result of `find` using a loop:

```
while read path; do
  grep -Eo "VIP_[0-9]+" "$path"
done < <(find . -type d -iname "VIP*_selected")
```

This should print a list of extracted paths.
Another way to this is using the `for` loop:

```
for path in $(find . -type d -iname "VIP*_selected"); do
  grep -Eo "VIP_[0-9]+" "$path"
done
```

Comment: Seems not working as 'grep' doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$  find . -type d -iname "VIP*" | cut -d'/' -f2 |sed -r 's/(.*)_.*/\1/g'
```

Comment: That returns a list of all the folders starting with 'VIP'; however, I want to return one folder starting with VIP at once.

Comment: With the help of that one by one in a time, what you are going to do in the process? Explain